# Согласование числительного с существительным

Tags: согласование, числительные, окончания

53 тысячи квадратных километрОВ или 53 тысячи квадратных километрА?
Верно склонение на «А», как «три больших окна»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *53 тысячи квадратных километр**ов***.

три окна – три тысячи окон
53 километр**а** – 53 тысячи километр**ов**

Окончание будет зависеть уже не от числительного "три", а от слова "тысяча".

> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=276958)
>
> Верно: *2,5 тысячи квадратных метров.*